# Highcharts draggable point drag step size

Tags: highcharts, drag, points

In following example, I need to drag the point by certain step size, e.g. by 10. See

```
drag: function (e) {
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petiska/6g9tqrh5/28/)

Comment: What is your question? You may want to review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question should include all relevant code, as well as a clearly stated question and any attempts made so far. "Step" is also kind of ambiguous given that the line graph is `step: 'left'`. Could you describe some drag step scenarios (in the question)? For example, should the steps be relative to the original value of the point? If your point is at value 92, and step size is 5, do you go to 95 or 97?

Comment: If the point is 92 and the step is 5,  it should go 95, 100, 105. And also I need this step size=5 for first 8 points and for the rest of points I need step size=2.

Comment: Hi Petr Perner, please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/as5jL8q0/ and let me know if you are looking for something like that or similar?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, here's a modified version of `draggable-points.js` ([GitRaw](https://rawgit.com/Ondkloss/draggable-points/dynamic-drag-and-drag-steps/draggable-points.js) [GitHub](https://github.com/Ondkloss/draggable-points/blob/dynamic-drag-and-drag-steps/draggable-points.js)) that allows some parameters for dragging in certain step sizes. The following options have been added for a series:

- `dragStepSizeX`: numeric step size for X-axis
- `dragStepSizeY`: numeric step size for Y-axis
- `dragStepSize`: function taking the parameters `XorY` and `point`, which you can implement to return the desired step size depending on the axis and the point being dragged
- `dragStepAllowMinMax`: boolean, should you be allowed to drag to the min/max limit, or enforce steps?
- `dragStepRelative`: boolean, should drag steps be done relative to the points original value?

See [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6g9tqrh5/58/) of it being used to enforce step sizes on the Y-axis of 5 for the 8 first point, and 2 for the remaining points. Not step size on X-axis.

The following functions have been modified to accomodate this in `draggable-points.js`:

```
/**
 * Adjust value according to step size
 */
function dragStepAdjustment(value, prevValue, stepSize, relative) {
    if(stepSize === undefined) {
        return value;
    }

    const midpoint = stepSize/2;
    const modulus = relative === true ? (value-prevValue)%stepSize : value%stepSize;
    return modulus > midpoint ? value + (stepSize-modulus) : value - modulus;
}

/**
 * Filter by dragMin and dragMax
 */
function filterRange(newY, point, series, stepSize, XOrY) {
    var options = series.options,
        dragMin = pick(options.dragMin ? options.dragMin(XOrY, point) : undefined, options['dragMin' + XOrY], undefined),
        dragMax = pick(options.dragMax ? options.dragMax(XOrY, point) : undefined, options['dragMax' + XOrY], undefined),
        precision = pick(options['dragPrecision' + XOrY], undefined),
        allowMinMax = options.dragStepAllowMinMax === true;

    if (!isNaN(precision)) {
        newY = Math.round(newY / precision) * precision;
    }

    if (newY < dragMin) {
        if(stepSize !== undefined) {
            allowMinMax ? newY = dragMin : newY += stepSize;
        }
        else {
            newY = dragMin;
        }
    } else if (newY > dragMax) {
        if(stepSize !== undefined) {
            allowMinMax ? newY = dragMax : newY -= stepSize;
        }
        else {
            newY = dragMax;
        }
    }

    if(newY < dragMin || newY > dragMax) {
        newY = 'X' == XOrY ? point.x : point.y;
    }

    return newY;
}

/**
 * Get the new values based on the drag event
 */
function getNewPos(e) {
    var originalEvent = e.originalEvent || e,
        pageX = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
        pageY = originalEvent.changedTouches ? originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY,
        series = dragPoint.series,
        draggableX = series.options.draggableX && dragPoint.draggableX !== false,
        draggableY = series.options.draggableY && dragPoint.draggableY !== false,
        dragSensitivity = pick(series.options.dragSensitivity, 1),
        deltaX = draggableX ? dragX - pageX : 0,
        deltaY = draggableY ? dragY - pageY : 0,
        newPlotX = dragPlotX - deltaX,
        newPlotY = dragPlotY - deltaY,
        newX = dragX === undefined ? dragPoint.x : series.xAxis.toValue(newPlotX, true),
        newY = dragY === undefined ? dragPoint.y : series.yAxis.toValue(newPlotY, true),
        dragStepSizeX = pick(series.options.dragStepSize ? series.options.dragStepSize('X', dragPoint) : undefined, series.options.dragStepSizeX, undefined),
        dragStepSizeY = pick(series.options.dragStepSize ? series.options.dragStepSize('Y', dragPoint) : undefined, series.options.dragStepSizeY, undefined),
        ret;

    newX = dragStepAdjustment(newX, dragPoint.x, dragStepSizeX, series.options.dragStepRelative);
    newY = dragStepAdjustment(newY, dragPoint.y, dragStepSizeY, series.options.dragStepRelative);
    newX = filterRange(newX, dragPoint, series, dragStepSizeX, 'X');
    newY = filterRange(newY, dragPoint, series, dragStepSizeY, 'Y');
    if (dragPoint.low) {
        var newPlotHigh = dragPlotHigh - deltaY,
            newPlotLow = dragPlotLow - deltaY;
        newHigh = dragY === undefined ? dragPoint.high : series.yAxis.toValue(newPlotHigh, true);
        newLow = dragY === undefined ? dragPoint.low : series.yAxis.toValue(newPlotLow, true);
        newHigh = dragStepAdjustment(newHigh, dragPoint.y, dragStepSizeY, series.options.dragStepRelative);
        newLow = dragStepAdjustment(newLow, dragPoint.y, dragStepSizeY, series.options.dragStepRelative);
        newHigh = filterRange(newHigh, dragPoint, series, dragStepSizeY, 'Y');
        newLow = filterRange(newLow, dragPoint, series, dragStepSizeY, 'Y');
    }
    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2)) > dragSensitivity) {
        return {
            x: draggableX ? newX : dragPoint.x,
            y: draggableY ? newY : dragPoint.y,
            high: (draggableY && !changeLow) ? newHigh : dragPoint.high,
            low: (draggableY && changeLow) ? newLow : dragPoint.low,
            dragStart: dragStart,
            originalEvent: e
        };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is a modification of the code of Torstein Honsi of Highsoft, under the MIT License.